# Dealing with params when sending a get request

Tags: reactjs

I have this request and it is for the return of all my Spaces.

And I want to make a function to deal with the backend, and I want to pass the parameter "workspaceId".

And the question is how can I do that?

```
GET:{{url}}/spaces?workspaceId=60e33c7cc447c80015bdbdab
```

function:

```
 getAllSpaces: async () => {
        const response = await api.get(
            "spaces/:workspaceId"
        ).then(res=>{
            console.log('values inside zustand 2: ')
            console.log('response inside zustand 3: ', res);


            set(state =>{
                state.space = res.data;
            })
            console.log('response data: ', res.data)
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

Comment: You can call the API using the default `fetch` API.
Here's the link to it....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

or you can use `axios` to call your APIs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 1):

**You haven't mentioned your library, that's why I'm using axios. It's quite popular in react**

Use axios, quite easy and readable:

```
axios.get(this.state.url+'/spaces', {
  params: {
    workspaceId: this.state.workspaceId
  }
}).then((res)=>{
   ...
});
```